# Why mixing hot syrup (sugar + water) into yolks in sabayon?

Tags: eggs, dessert, melting-sugar

Recently I browsed for tiramisu recipes where *ricotta* replaces the *mascarpone*.

In this particular (italian) [recipe](http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Tiramisu-di-ricotta.html) the sabayon is started by adding hot syrup to whipped yolks: I have always mixed crystal sugar to yolks.

What is the point of using hot syrup instead of sugar?

Comment: It's not "hot melted sugar", The recipe calls for a syrup (made with sugar and water) `in un pentolino versate lo zucchero, unite l’acqua (17), mescolate leggermente per far inumidire lo zucchero, poi scaldate lo sciroppo a fuoco moderato avendo cura di inserire un termometro per alimenti così da monitorare la temperatura che dovrà raggiungere i 121°`. The reason is to make the sabayon firmer, like an italian meringue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sabayon, you have to cook the eggs to hold the foam. Normally, you first mix air into the (cold) sugar and yolk, then heat on a water bath. This looks like an alternative method for heating the yolks, similar to the Italian method for meringue.

I haven't used it, so cannot tell you how much it differs. If it behaves like Italian meringue, it will probably produce a slightly more stable foam, but with less volume, and will taste sweeter.

Comment: The sweetness depends on the sugar contents, not matter if it's granulated sugar, confectioner's sugar or a sugar syrup.

Comment: @roetnig no, the method of preparation also matters. There can be many different reasons behind it (e.g. needing more sugar to achieve the same texture, or having a denser foam so you have more sugar per bite, etc.) Empirically, Italian meringue is sweeter than French meringue.

Comment: If the quantity of sugar is the same, you will perceive the same sweetness. The differences using regular, caster, confectioners sugar or syrup in different states of hardness is the structure, the texture, etc. But the amount of sugar is what gives the sweetness.

Comment: First, no, you will perceive different sweetness at the same amount. Taste 
is not simple linear sensing of chemistry. Second, different methods are likely to require different amounts too.

Comment: Whatever.. I won't discuss what is evident. Try it yourself.

Comment: @roetnig - you certainly can perceive sweetness differently with the same amount - density, surface area, texture, and homogeneity all play a role.  The same amount of sugar will taste sweeter in grains than a candy (sensing sugar-per-time).  With tea, the reverse is true - ground sugar will dissolve and be diluted, so it feels like less sugar per volume than drinking with a candy on the tongue concentrating sugar right at the tastebuds.  This recipe, denser foam might mean more sugar in less volume, or texture leaving sugar easier to sense, or changing how one eats it (thus sugar-over-time).